# Problema con OSX Macbook Pro

Tags: macos

Recientemente el MacBook dejo de funcionar, apareciendo constantemente el circulo arcoiris por largos minutos apenas abro una app o realizo cualquier acción, reaccionando extremadamente lento. Formateé el disco duro e hice una instalación limpia del sistema operativo OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 , solucionando el problema momentáneamente, pero al día siguiente volvió a tener los mismos problemas. Hice un chequeo con Apple Hardware Test (completo) y no se encontraron errores.Realice un chequeo al disco duro a través de Utilidad de discos y no se encontraron errores. Inicie con modo Arranque seguro y funciona todo relativamente bien (estoy acá en este momento, pero también se congela a veces, pero el tiempo de reacción es menor al arranque normal), también limpie caché, saqué los ítems de inicio de sesión, elimine ítems de Librería/StartupItems, ~Librería/LaunchAgents, Librería/LaunchAgents , Librería/LaunchDeamons (ninguno tenia que ver con OSX, eran casi todos de Adobe, y alguno de Utorrent)

Después de realizar todo esto en modo arranque normal sigue teniendo problemas con cualquier actividad, y solo corre de forma "fluida" en modo arranque seguro.

Si alguien puede darme alguna idea de que otras acciones realizar para poder solucionar este problema estaría muy agradecido, ya que necesito con urgencia que pueda volver a estar operativo. Para ampliar la idea del uso, trabajo mucho con After Effects, Final Cut, Photoshop, Ilustrador y Logic. Siempre funcionó excelente con todos los programas.
Es un Macbook Pro 13' mid 2012
4 gb RAM

Comment: Esta pregunta no entra dentro del alcance de este sitio ya que no versa sobre programación sino que parece más para soporte técnico de Apple, y corre el riesgo de ser cerrada.

Comment: No sabia que solo se podía preguntar sobre programación. La verdad le pregunte a un conocido informático y me señalo que preguntara en este sitio. Consulte con el mismo texto en los foros de comunidad de Apple y aun no tengo respuesta. Y como estoy fuera de garantía el soporte técnico de Apple no me escuchara a menos que suelte dinero.

Comment: Yo tuve un problema similar y fue por falta de espacio en el disco duro: el sistema operativo se pasaba más tiempo pensando (y supongo que paginando en memoria) que haciendo cualquier otra cosa. Pero si has formateado, ese no debería ser el problema.

Comment: ¿Crees que debería intentar instalando la versión 10.11.3 (downgradearlo) o el Yosemite en su defecto para descartar ? Por que al menos en Yosemite, no me dio problema. Pero igual tengo que tomar en cuenta que tengo El Capitan hace varios meses y tampoco me había dado problema. Hasta ahora.

Comment: Asegúrate de que has echo una instalación limpia. Lo mejor es utilizando un USB y asegúrate que es limpia. Tiene pinta de virus/algún problema de software que entonces se tiene que solucionar con esa instalación. Si es un problema de hardware ya es otra cosa pero por lo que has dicho no es el caso. Hay otras comunidades de StackExchange (en inglés) que creo pueden ayudarte.

Comment: Mi problema fue similar y tenía relación directa con la RAM. OSX El Capitan con 4GB de RAM no era buena combinación. Tocó ir a versiones anteriores que consumen menos memoria.

Comment: Lo mismo que comenta Oscar R., El Capitan con 4GB de RAM no es una opción a menos que tengas un disco de estado sólido, aunque indica que no consume mas recursos, en realidad si, yo tuve que regresar a Yosemite...

Comment: Leyendo en hartos foros ayer, y hablando con gente mas experimentada, me dijeron que en realidad podría ser un problema de hardware no detectado, mas específicamente el cable flex que conecta el disco duro a la placa madre. No creo que sea software o problemas de RAM, ya que inmediatamente me tendría que haber dado problemas desde el comienzo, y no fue así. O eso pienso con mi escaso conocimiento del tema